# Crystal Reports- Passing one parameter value to multiple database fields

Tags: sql, parameters, crystal-reports

I have a table in the database that has 10 application fields (App#0 to App#9) and their corresponding application versions (appversion#0 to appversion#9)

I have created a new parameter using dynamic cascading that prompts the user to Select an Application: and select the corresponding Application Version:
The value for this fields are taken from App#0 and Appversion#0 respectively.

I want to select all records in the database where application corresponds to the selected App and Appversion. So in the select expert I have used this parameter and it shows me the correct records.

The problem now is- The app that user selects can be in any of the database fields from app#0 to app#9. It is not necessary that it will always be in the app#0 field. So, I want crystal report to check all the database fields from app#0 to app#9 with the parameter that the user selects. How can I do that without creating multiple parameters?

Select Formula expert query

SELECT `issue1`.`reference_id`, `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`product`, `issue1`.`description`, `issue1`.`last_mod_date`, `issue1`.`owner_id`, 
 `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`application0`, `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`application_version0`, `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`priority`, `state1`.`name`, 
 FROM
    (`splatt`.`issue` `issue1` 
        INNER JOIN `splatt`.`Software_Products_Anomaly` `Software_Products_Anomaly1` 
        ON `issue1`.`id`=`Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`issue_id`
    ) 
INNER JOIN `splatt`.`state` `state1` 
ON `issue1`.`status`=`state1`.`id`
WHERE
    (   `state1`.`name`='assigned' 
        OR `state1`.`name`='open' 
        OR `state1`.`name`='reassigned' 
        OR `state1`.`name`='submitted'
    ) 
    AND `issue1`.`owner_id`<>113 
    AND `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`product`='PHX' 
    AND
    ( `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`application0`='Package1' AND `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`application_version0`<='2.2.2.2')
ORDER BY `Software_Products_Anomaly1`.`priority`

Comment: can you post your select expert formula?

Comment: please see the updated question for details about the query. The query was too big to be posted as a comment.